# How can we register IHttpContextAccessor in startup class in asp.net 2.1 core application?

Tags: asp.net-core

We have an application in which User.Identity.Name is null for only one user. I have declared IHttpContextAccessor as static like below.

```
public static IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;
```

I found something in the internet. Asp.net core will allow concurrent request at a time. If we declare IHttpContextAccessor as static, it will valid for first request alone. Please refer the
[link.](https://forums.asp.net/p/2144161/6219259.aspx?Only%20one%20person%20gets%20HttpContext%20Null%20error%20Updated%20)

As per the above reference, i have changed  IHttpContextAccessor declaration from static to readonly.  Also i changed the class where this IHttpContextAccessor declared, was changed from static to non static. So i have created object to access the class members in the places where we are accessing that class members.

But in startup class, i could see the below code in configure method. Since i have declared IHttpContextAccessor as readonly, it giving below compile error for the below code.

```
getScopedServices.HttpContextAccessor = services.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
```

[image: Error screenshot]

What is the use of above code? i have already registered IHttpContextAccessor as singleton in Configure Services section like below. Do we really require the above code?

```
 #region Singleton

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        #endregion Singleton
```

what will happen if we remove the below line from the code? Please help me on this.

```
getScopedServices.HttpContextAccessor = services.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: in your `startup.cs` you need to inject it by calling this: `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` then you can get in your DI classes by using the `IHttpContextAccessor` object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: We don't suggest you register the httocontextaccessor as Singleton, since the httcontextaccessor is per request. If you register it as Singleton, it will never changed. Besides, we couldn't understand what's your actually requirement. Do you mean you want to use httcontextaccessor in startup.cs's configure method?

Comment: You mean that we just need to add services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); in startup.cs and we can remove below code from startup.cs file right?   getScopedServices.HttpContextAccessor = services.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>(); #region Singleton

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        #endregion Singleton

Comment: My requirement is that i want to change IHttpContextAccessor object declaration from static to readonly in DI classes. If i change it to readonly, am getting compile error in the below line getScopedServices.HttpContextAccessor = services.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>(); Do we really need this line in startup.cs file? what will happen if we remove it? once it is removed, what is the best way to register HttpContextAccessor in startup.cs?